# Babel cli does not generate JS for browser

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am trying to generate JS using Babel.
My purpose is to use ES6 for the Browser, I know there are different ways to setup it, but at first I'd like to do it manually.

This is what I did:

- I installed babel-cli
- I created 2 folders src and lib (the ES6 code is in the src and lib contains the output generated by babel), and I put some basic js code inside src.
- then I issued `babel src --out-dir lib --watch`

I would exec that the output code generated by Babel does not contain ES6 features like import/export, but it does contain it. So I cannot use it in the Brower.

What is wrong?

Comment: How have you told Babel what the transpile target JS version is?

Comment: I have not, the only steps I did are those that I listed. I'm going to check for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Babel, itself, isn't a module bundler. It *supports* module bundlers like Webpack, Browserify, RequireJS, etc. if you tell it what kind you use, but it doesn't do the actual bundling. Pick a bundling system, and then consult its documentation for how you integrate Babel into it.

Comment: Thanks for the useful explanation, I started with the wrong assumption that babel manages modules too. I'm reading the doc
http://webpack.github.io/docs/usage.html#transpiling-es2015-using-babel-loader, even if I find it not so good, I agree with the first meme :)

Comment: So I am having a similar issue as described in the question, where Babel doesn't do anything upon running the "npm build" where ""build": "babel input.js --out-file compiled.js"" is in the script tag. 
@TJ, in your answer you mention that Babel isnt a bundler, does it need to be for that command to work? According to the documentation, it appears that this command will simply transpile the code, with no need to bundle.